# How to split string by a special character and get into 2 separate variables in pl sql

Tags: string, plsql, split

There is a text

> 'example1,example2'

I want to get this text into a 2 variables split by the comma.
So end result should be

> variable1 = 'example1'
>
> variable2 = 'example2'

How to do this on PL SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain SQL you can do it as below:

```
SELECT 'example1,example2',
       LTRIM (
          SUBSTR ('example1,example2', INSTR ('example1,example2', ',', 1)),
          ',')
          variable2,
       RTRIM (
          SUBSTR ('example1,example2', 1, INSTR ('example1,example2', ',')),
          ',')
          variable1
  FROM DUAL;
```

In a PLSQL block you can do it as follow:

```
DECLARE
   variable1   VARCHAR2 (20);
   variable2   VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   SELECT LTRIM (
             SUBSTR ('example1,example2',
                     INSTR ('example1,example2', ',', 1)),
             ',')
             variable1,
          RTRIM (
             SUBSTR ('example1,example2',
                     1,
                     INSTR ('example1,example2', ',')),
             ',')
             variable2
     INTO variable2, variable1
     FROM DUAL;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('variable1=''' || variable1 || '''');

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('variable2=''' || variable2 || '''');
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this using INSTR and SUBSTRING functions.

**INSTR** function gives location of desired iteration of a particular character inside the string. Using this function you can find the location of the delimiter ','

**SUBSTRING** function as per its name, return a substring from the input string. It takes start location and optional end location and return the substring between start and end point.

The following code demonstrates the usage:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
input VARCHAR2(100):='example1,example2'; -- input string
VARIABLE1 VARCHAR2(100); 
VARIABLE2 VARCHAR2(100);
begin
VARIABLE1 := substr(input,1,INSTR(input,',',1)-1);
VARIABLE2 := substr(input,INSTR(input,',',1)+1);
dbms_output.put_line(input);
dbms_output.put_line(VARIABLE1);
dbms_output.put_line(VARIABLE2);
end;
```